# Having trouble running Jest tests: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, babeljs, jestjs

I know this may have been posted before, but I'm really stuck as to why my tests aren't working in my React project. Here's my `.babelrc` file:

```
{
    "presets": ["react", "es2015", "stage-0"],

    "plugins": [
        "transform-runtime",
        "add-module-exports",
        "transform-decorators-legacy"
    ],

    "env": {
        "development": {
            "plugins": [
                "typecheck",
                ["react-transform", {
                    "transforms": [{
                        "transform": "react-transform-catch-errors",
                        "imports": ["react", "redbox-react"]
                    }]
                }]
            ]
        },
        "test": {
            "presets": ["es2015", "react", "stage-0"],
            "plugins": [
                "transform-runtime",
                "add-module-exports",
                "transform-decorators-legacy"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

and here is my Jest setting in `package.json`

```
  "jest": {
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "jsx",
      "json"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "ExampleTest": "<rootDir>/app/pages/ExampleTest.js"
    },
    "moduleDirectories": [
      "app",
      "node_modules"
    ]
  },
```

The error that I'm getting is `Test suite failed to run... SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`.

From what I can tell about that error, the files that it is trying to run have JSX/ES6 code in them... and it doesn't know how to transpile that? Which is weird because I've told it to do just that in the `.babelrc`. I have also provided Jest with the appropriate `moduleDirectories`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

the last comma ,  in your JSON is wrong. It should look like:

```
{"root":{
    "presets": ["react", "es2015", "stage-0"],

    "plugins": [
        "transform-runtime",
        "add-module-exports",
        "transform-decorators-legacy"
    ],

    "env": {
        "development": {
            "plugins": [
                "typecheck",
                ["react-transform", {
                    "transforms": [{
                        "transform": "react-transform-catch-errors",
                        "imports": ["react", "redbox-react"]
                    }]
                }]
            ]
        },
        "test": {
            "presets": ["es2015", "react", "stage-0"],
            "plugins": [
                "transform-runtime",
                "add-module-exports",
                "transform-decorators-legacy"
            ]
        }
    }
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you import `React` in your test file.

Comment: I am already doing this at the top of my test file. `import React from 'react'`

Answer (score 0):

If your package.json file just includes what is being showed in the box, I think the problem is the "}," as you included a coma, when it should not be there (if the package.json file just includes what is displayed in the box), because it is the last line of code, and there is no more JSON code following it. Hope it is useful!

Answer (score 0):

The answer, if anyone curious, is to configure Jest to gracefully handle asset files such as stylesheets and images. Usually, these files aren't particularly useful in tests so we can safely mock them out. To learn more, see [Using with Webpack](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/webpack.html) in the Jest documentation.